# Trouble replicating a simple OR table (Bayesian meta-analysis)

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I'm reading [this](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ecjd11/charles_dimaggio/DIRE/styled-4/styled-11/code-9/) intro to meta analysis from Columbia University, and I cannot replicate the Log OR in the very first table.

[image]

For the first study:

OR = (1/39)/(2/34) = .03/.06 = 0.44
Log OR = log(0.44) = -0.36

Where as the table shows -0.83. I'm puzzled. What elementary thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the log to base 10. You need to take the natural log. For example, in R, the `log()` function does that (`log10()` for the log to base 10):

```
log((1/39)/(2/34))
[1] -0.8303483
```

as in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The excerpt says the log odds ratios are normal approximated. Run the following R code to reproduce the results:

```
library(meta)
df <- data.frame(study=c("Morton", "Rasmussen","Smith","Abraham","Feldsted","Schechter","Ceremuzynski","LIMIT-2"),
                 MagDeaths=c(1, 9, 2, 1, 10, 1, 1, 90),
                 MagPatients=c(40, 135, 200, 48, 150, 59, 25, 1159),
                 PlaceboDeaths=c(2, 23, 7, 1, 8, 9, 3, 118),
                 PlaceboPatients=c(36, 135, 200, 46, 148, 56, 23, 1157))
fit <- metabin(MagDeaths, MagPatients, PlaceboDeaths, PlaceboPatients, data = df, sm="OR", fixed=TRUE, random=FALSE)
print(fit$TE) # print estimated treatment effects
print(fit$seTE) # print estimated standard errors of treatment effects
```